# Dynamic Form fields not sent to CGI script

Tags: javascript, perl, forms, file-upload, cgi

I am attempting to have a file upload page that allows for an arbitrary amount of file uploads. I found javascript code that successfully creates a new file input field in the form when one is clicked, however, any fields besides the one hardcoded in html are not being sent to my perl CGI script.

Javascript

```
    function fileFields() {
         var x = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
         x.onclick = function() {
                var i = parseFloat(this.lastChild.id)+1;
                input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("type", "file");
                input.setAttribute("name", 'fileName_' + i);
                input.setAttribute("id", i);
                this.appendChild(input);
         }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  fileFields();
});
```

HTML Form

```
<form action="https://www.indiana.edu/~webdeviu/phil/submit.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="property">
     <TMPL_LOOP NAME="PROPS">
          <option value="<TMPL_VAR NAME="user">"><TMPL_VAR NAME="user"></option>
     </TMPL_LOOP>
</select>
<br />
<a href="#" id="fileUpload"><input type="file" name="file_1" id="1" /></a>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Perl CGI, portion that looks for multiple files

```
my @files;

my $i = 1;
my $file = $query->param("file_" . $i);
while ($file) {
    push(@files, $file);
    $i = $i + 1;
    $file = $query->param("file_" . $i);
}
print $query->header( );
print scalar(@files); # prints 1 regardless of how many files I upload
exit;
```

I also put an escape in the while loop at one point to print out $file once it is changed to "file_2", and it is null at that point.

What am I missing? any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have an input element called file_2, it's called fileName_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've named the dynamic file fields incorrectly:

`input.setAttribute("name", 'fileName_' + i);`

That should be this according to your CGI:

`input.setAttribute("name", 'file_' + i);`

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging with firebug. See what is actually sent and how the HTML form is constructed in real time.

Comment: Probably the single most usefull tool for web development.